# I am trying to build a data frame that shows a culmination of all transactions for each day (not using for loop)

Tags: r

For each day, I want to see a culmination of all transactions that have happened up to that day (using As_Of_Dt as the indicator of the current day). E.g. on the first day (1/1/22), there was only one transaction so would expect to see one row for that As_Of_Dt. Second day (1/2/2022), there had been two transactions, so would expect to see three transactions for that As_Of_Dt (the two transactions from 1/2/22, plus the one transaction from 1/1/22), etc for all days going forward.

Below is an example of a dataset where I was able to do this using a for loop, however my real dataset is much larger and I am looking for a faster solution (maybe using the `apply` family?)

```
df <- data.frame(TradeDate = c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-02", "2022-01-03","2022-01-04"),
                 Ticker = c("AAPL", "AMZN", "META", "AAPL","TSLA"),
                 Type = c("Buy", "Buy", "Buy", "Buy","Buy"),
                 Shares = c(10, 12, 5, 15, 20))

df1 <- df[0, ]
dtStart <- as_date("2022-01-01")
dtEnd <- as_date("2022-01-04")
dtRng <- interval(dtStart, dtEnd) %/% days(1) + 1


for(i in 1:dtRng){
  df2 <- df %>%
    filter(TradeDate <= (dtStart + i - 1)) %>%
    mutate(As_Of_Dt = as_date(dtStart) + i - 1)
  df1 <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
}
```

| TradeDate | Ticker | Type | Shares | As_Of_Dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | AAPL | Buy | 10 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-01 | AAPL | Buy | 10 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-02 | AMZN | Buy | 12 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-02 | META | Buy | 5 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-01 | AAPL | Buy | 10 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-02 | AMZN | Buy | 12 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-02 | META | Buy | 5 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-03 | AAPL | Buy | 15 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-01 | AAPL | Buy | 10 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2022-01-02 | AMZN | Buy | 12 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2022-01-02 | META | Buy | 5 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2022-01-03 | AAPL | Buy | 15 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2022-01-04 | TSLA | Buy | 20 | 2022-01-04 |

I tried doing this by replacing the for loop with a function and inputting the function into `lapply`, however I am not very familiar with the `apply` family and had issues iterating the filter for each day.

Comment: One way you could do this efficiently would be by using a non-equi join, which is possible using data.table, sqldf, or the development version of dplyr. If your data isn't too big, you could also do a sort of cartesian join (ie join every date to every transaction) and filter out the transactions that came after the operative date, like `library(dplyr); df %>% distinct(as_of = TradeDate) %>% left_join(df, by = character()) %>%  filter(TradeDate <= as_of)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this is more efficient that your loop, but not as efficient as a non-equi join.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  distinct(as_of = TradeDate) %>%
  left_join(df, by = character()) %>%
  filter(TradeDate <= as_of)
```

Or using the dev version of dplyr which introduces non-equi joins

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
df %>% 
  distinct(as_of = TradeDate) %>%
  left_join(df, join_by(as_of >= TradeDate))
```

Result

```
        as_of  TradeDate Ticker Type Shares
1  2022-01-01 2022-01-01   AAPL  Buy     10
2  2022-01-02 2022-01-01   AAPL  Buy     10
3  2022-01-02 2022-01-02   AMZN  Buy     12
4  2022-01-02 2022-01-02   META  Buy      5
5  2022-01-03 2022-01-01   AAPL  Buy     10
6  2022-01-03 2022-01-02   AMZN  Buy     12
7  2022-01-03 2022-01-02   META  Buy      5
8  2022-01-03 2022-01-03   AAPL  Buy     15
9  2022-01-04 2022-01-01   AAPL  Buy     10
10 2022-01-04 2022-01-02   AMZN  Buy     12
11 2022-01-04 2022-01-02   META  Buy      5
12 2022-01-04 2022-01-03   AAPL  Buy     15
13 2022-01-04 2022-01-04   TSLA  Buy     20
```

Comment: perfect, went with the dplyr version (not the non-equi join) as this works well for my purposes. thanks for the help!